# Need help about the meaning of this sentence, describing the skin and its smoothness

Tags: meaning, manga, japanese-to-english

> それでいて手のひらにしっとり密着する肌は、**絹のようにきめ細やかで仄かに汗に濡れているのにこの上なく滑やかだ**。

I'm having trouble with this sentence, describing the skin and it's smoothness. If anyone can please help me correct my understanding if it's wrong.

My guess at this is " However her skin that clings to the palm of my hand is as smooth as silk, and even though it is slightly wet with sweat, it is extremely smooth."

(especially at these parts 絹のようにきめ細やかで  and この上なく滑やかだ )

Answer (score 1):

I think your interpretation is basically correct.

The structure is '...肌は、...きめ細やかで...滑らかだ。'. So it repeats descriptions of smoothness of the skin.

- 絹のようにきめ細やかで *smooth like silk and*
- 仄かに汗で濡れているのにこの上なく滑やかだ *slightly wet with sweat yet extremely smooth*

この上なく literally *in the way that it is impossible to be more so* (*so* refers to smoothness here). It is like a superlative without particular comparison (as [this](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-very-a-most-the-most-interesting-idea-absolute-superlative.2796976/)).

Now the difference between きめ細やか and 滑やか is harder to explain. きめ細やか means that the 'mesh' of the surface is fine while 滑やか means that the surface has little 'unevenness'.

Note [滑]{すべ}やか is rather literary and usually it is [滑]{なめ}**ら**か. As the character suggests, it implies an object moves without much resistance on the surface, slippery. This might sound contradictory to the preceding 汗で濡れている**のに** because to be *wet with sweat* usually enhances the slipperiness. I guess the intention here    is that the skin does not 'stick' even with sweat.

Comment: you mean "it does not feels sticky in the palm of MC's hand, even when her skin is a little bit sweaty " ?

Comment: Yes. A common phrase describing the usual feeling is 汗でべたべたする (*to feel sticky with sweat*) as opposed to the sentence in the question.